# How do I get this nested schema working in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to figure out how to how to save multiple commands in a command list but everything I've tried hasn't worked. This is how I have it set up so far but when it saves, it saves in the format of

```
"command_list" : [ { "action" : "goto,goto", "target" : "http://www.google.com,http://www.cnn.com" } ]
```

when I really want something like

```
"command_list" : [ "command" : { "action" : "goto", "target" : "http://www.google.com" },                     
                   "command" : { "action" : "goto", "target" : "http://www.cnn.com" } ]
```

where there are multiple commands. So far my app.js is storing the data like this

```
var configSample = new Configurations({
        command_list_size: request.body.command_list_size,
        command_list: [ {action: request.body.action, target: request.body.target}] 
});
```

and the model looks like this

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var command = mongoose.Schema({
    action: String,
    target: String
});

var configSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    command_list_size: Number,
    command_list: [command] 
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Configurations', configSchema);
```

So how do I get that nesting action going? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not packing the data right when you send it to the server. If you use the following:

```
command_list: [ {action: request.body.action, target: request.body.target}]
```

it's going to grab all of the actions and lump them together and do the same with the targets. You'd be better off sending an array to your server with the documents already nested in them.

The other option would be to parse the data to pull out the elements once you receive it on your server, but I think it'd be easier to just package it right in the first place.

ADDITION:

If you wanted to split what you have, you could use the String.split() method and rebuild the object:

```
// not certain the chaining will work like this, but you get the idea. It works
// on the string values you'll receive
var actions = response.body.action.split(',');
var targets = response.body.target.split(',');

// the Underscore library provides some good tools to manipulate what we have
// combined the actions and targets arrays
var combinedData = _.zip(actions, targets);

// go through the combinedData array and create an object with the correct keys
var commandList = _.map(combinedData, function(value) { 
    return _.object(["action", "target"], value)
});
```

There may be a better way to create the new object, but this does the trick.

EDIT:

I created a question about trying [to refactor the above code here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732825/how-to-break-up-an-object-with-a-string-of-values-to-create-a-new-array-of-objec)